# Relationship between PDO class and PDOStatement class

Tags: php, mysql, cursor, pdo

I'm a php and mysql beginner, I'm currently self study PDO and confused some concepts:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$users = $dbh->query($sql);
```

1.What is the relationship between PDO class and PDOStatement class?

`$dbh` is the new object of class [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), but why $users is the [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object? `fetchAll()` is the function inside class `PDOStatement`, but you can use it like this `$users->fetchAll()`, is `$users` a `PDO` or `PDOStatement` object?

2.Someone said $users is the cursor, once consumed, it won't rewind to the beginning of the resultset.

```
foreach ($users as $row) {
    print $row["name"] . "<br/>";
}
```

but why you can use it in a `foreach` statement? `foreach` provides a way to iterate over arrays. what is cursor actually? is cursor a pointer?

3.For the [pdostatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class, the doc said:

```
PDOStatement implements Traversable { ... }
```

why this class implements Traversable interface? is it empty interface?

Thank you for help!

Comment: 3. The very sample you're citing shows `Traversable` as a link... to a page where the [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface is explained.

Comment: oh, Traversable  detect if a class is traversable using foreach. why PDOStatement class need to do this?

Comment: ... because it is convenient for users to iterate over a result set with a `foreach`?

Comment: As for point 1, `mysql_connect` returns a connection, and `mysql_query` returns a result set. In the PDO world, `PDO` and `PDOStatement` have roughly the same relationship - the first one represents a connection and the second one represents a result set of a particular query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), the `Traversable` interface allows you to use the object into a `foreach` loop and it's only supposed to be used internally. Think of it as a convenient way of using the PDOStatement.

Basically, with PDO there is two ways to execute a query, one by using [PDO::prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) & [PDOStatement::execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and the other one by using [PDO::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php). The later does prepare/execute in one call.

`PDO::query()` and `PDO::execute()` will not return the results on the other hand the PDOStatement object will allow you to specify the data you want to return. [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) will allow to define how you want to have your data organized.

It seems more complicated on first sight but it provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

All that mess is called "syntax sugar" and intended to sweeten a developer's life, though in real it makes taste too sugary to the point of disgust.

So, there are *two* kinds of object's characteristics - natural and unnatural ones.
And all your confusion come from the latter.

In your place I'd just forget of them, using objects straight way.

> 1.What is the relationship between PDO class and PDOStatement class?

That's 2 different classes. They serve different purposes. Like in old mysql you had connection resource and result resource. You have only one connection/PDO instance, but there can be any number actual query results/stmt classes.

> but why you can use it in a foreach statement?

That's the very syntax sugar I talked above. They just added such a possibility to the statement object.